# Animating a SVG Line in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, snap.svg

**Hello**

I'm creating and then animating SVG lines using this code, the first one doesen't work, but all of the rest does, what am I missing?

```
var newElement = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','line');
            newElement.setAttribute('class','travelPath');
            newElement.setAttribute('x1',currentCity.x);
            newElement.setAttribute('y1',currentCity.y);
            newElement.setAttribute('x2',nextCity.x+10);
            newElement.setAttribute('y2',nextCity.y+10);
            newElement.style.stroke="#3541b1";
            $("#theSVG").append(newElement);

            var length = newElement.getTotalLength();

            $(newElement).css({
                'stroke-dasharray': length+1,
                'stroke-dashoffset': length+1
            });

            $(newElement).animate({'stroke-dashoffset': 0}, 3000, mina.bounce);
```

The **length** variable comes back as 0 on the first console.log, but when I run it again at a later time, it comes back with the correct value, and animates in.

Almost as if the line hasen't been drawn before it tries to animate.

Comment: As it is just a simple line, why don't you just compute the length on your own?

Comment: Well because this method draws one of possibly 2.000 different lines, chosen by the user. How would you go about this Sirko?

Comment: `length = Math.sqrt( Math.pow( newCity.x + 10 -  currentCity.x, 2 ) + Math.pow( newCity.y + 10 -  currentCity.y, 2 ) )`. Hope I didn't forget any parenthesis.

Comment: Thank you mate, working. Still unclear why it failed in the first place though hah.

Answer (score 0):

getTotalLength isn't well supported to my understanding on a 'line' element.

You could convert this over to a path. Eg...

```
var newElement = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','path');
newElement.setAttribute('class','travelPath');
newElement.setAttribute('d', "M50,50L100,100")
newElement.style.stroke="#3541b1";

$("#theSVG").append(newElement);

var length = newElement.getTotalLength();
console.log( length )
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qngcn0sh/4/)

See if that helps at all.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I got it to work with the line element, and what I forgot to say is that I'm creating this for ONE screen only, a local one.

Answer (score 0):

As you have just a straight line in a Euclidean plane, you can just compute the length directly using:

```
let length = Math.sqrt( 
              Math.pow( newCity.x + 10 - currentCity.x, 2 ) + 
              Math.pow( newCity.y + 10 - currentCity.y, 2 ) 
             );
```